# in linux, prevent processes to go for sleep

Tags: linux, sleep

in linux (bullseye 11, kde ), prevent processes to go for sleep.

Problem: When I am away for couple hours and return to computer, I need 10-20 minutes to bring even my mouse in a state that I can use.  Especially processes that are essential. Eg. Mouse, in lxterminal, when it has as task to  download - continuously - videos, it responds after 10-20 minutes!!! Same with firefox, dolphin etc.

I DONT WANT to wait 10-20 minutes in order to use firefox, lxterminal, my mouse etc. I want to prevent these processes to go for sleep forever! I dont know how to do that.

What I have done (they dont prevent process sleeping):

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target
sudo systemctl mask suspend.target
sudo systemctl mask hibernate.target
sudo systemctl mask hybrid-sleep.target
sudo gsettings set org.gnome. sudo gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'nothing' settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 0
sudo setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0
```

Also, I removed autosuspend from all my usb disks and usb hubs with `powertop` (from good to bad state).

I dont know how to prevent process sleeping and make my desktop computer again USABLE!!!
This is very annoying. If there is any program to sent CONT signals to processes continuously, or any other method to prevent process sleeping, please tell me.

Note that memory is ~6/16GB, swap very low too (3GB/16GB), but CPU process almost 100%. When I try to move my mouse, I have observed that CPU process goes from 100% to 70% or lower. This means that tries to bring down "something" in order to free "process power". This takes much time. Because I download many things in many HDDs, the I/O processes is high too. I think it takes "CPU power" from "software" to "I/O disk" processes when I dont use the computer actively. Note that as I use the computer, no such problem is present.

However, this is made with wrong way. I dont know if I manipulate process priorities what effect I will have.  Linux, must give user the power to prevent processes from going to sleep (some or all).

```
  ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       ------------ 
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) x86_64 
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: B85M-HD3 R4 
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 5.11.0-18-generic 
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 26 days, 23 hours, 51 mins 
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 6834 (dpkg), 9 (flatpak) 
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.1.4 
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Resolution: 1920x1080 
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         DE: Plasma 5.21.4 
 `$$b      "-.__              WM: KWin 
  `Y$$                        Theme: Breeze Light [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2], Adwa 
   `Y$$.                      Icons: breeze [Plasma], breeze [GTK2/3] 
     `$$b.                    Terminal: lxterminal 
       `Y$$b.                 Terminal Font: Monospace 10 
          `"Y$b._             CPU: Intel i5-4570S (4) @ 3.600GHz 
              `"""            GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 1030 
                              Memory: 6059MiB / 15961MiB
```

Answer (score 0):

I adopted that script that do not help much but a bit:
Please, replace PID numbers with YOUR actual numbers of related processes.

You can close programs that you may forgot open to reduce mem and process power. you may replace kill by pkill if you dont want to use PID but name of process.

```
while true  
do  

# Sending continuation signals to process in order to prevent them from sleep. 
# somewhat succesfull

    #plasmashell
    sudo    kill -SIGCONT 1113
    #lxterminal
    sudo    kill -SIGCONT 1112
    #kwin_x11
    sudo    kill -SIGCONT 1111
    #kded5
    sudo    kill -SIGCONT 1114
    
    # usb hubs
    sudo     kill -SIGCONT  66682
    sudo     kill -SIGCONT  69861
    
    sleep 20  #or find Timecount function to replace sleep. 

#Kill processes by name that you may forgot open before eg. sleep

    sudo     pkill  -SIGKILL  thunderbird
    sudo     pkill  -SIGKILL  shutter
    
done
```

UPDATE (the above script was not running in any case)

- Case 1: 2 terminals open (wget download) + qbittorent + system monitor
- Case 2: 2 terminals open (wget download) + qbittorent + system monitor
- In case 1 before my sleep, I had written in search bar of system monitor "usb" and displayed or usb-storage processes. As long as I had this no "halt" or severe "lag" was experienced after waking up and going to use my computer. I had done this in order to watch when such processes were going for sleep.
- In case 2 before my sleep, no "usb" was written is search bar, and I experience "lag" in mouse movement and not able to do things eg. move a window, open something etc., when i left the bed and went to my computer.

I can suggest that system monitor sends some special signals to processes that are found in its search bar preventing them from creating lagging somehow? Dont know...